# AWS Snow devices- what event is generated when files are transferred to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-snowball

I'm trying to transfer files from an onsite Drobo to S3 Deep Archive.  Because of the way S3 stores things in Deep Storage, it never makes sense to archive objects which are 8KB or smaller (because you will pay for 8KB of Standard anyway).  Lifecycle rules are not smart enough to handle this logic, so I wrote a [lambda](https://github.com/fsiler/s3-archive/blob/main/working-lambda.py).  However, I'm not sure what trigger to use.  Right now, this lambda only responds to `ObjectCreated:Put` events- which works fine for my simple online testing, but I suspect may not work when I'm doing the transfer with a Snowcone or Snowball.  The lambda itself then causes an `ObjectCreated:Copy` event if it archives the file.

So in order to get this to work with Snowcone/Snowball, it'd be nice to know: what event is generated when the files are transferred off those devices into S3?  I've contemplated just using DynamoDB and pushing archived filenames into a table so I have a reference, but that seems unnecessary if I can get firm guidance.  Another option is to be brutish about it and simply force-archive on every event received, because as far as I can tell, it is as expensive to query the current storage class of the object as it is to attempt the change in storage class.

Checked all the docs, including the 184 page Snowcone User guide PDF.  [This blog article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html) suggests that the `Put` and `Post` events refer back to HTTP, but I don't think the Snow family existed at the time.  I tweeted at Jeff Barr and haven't heard back yet.  Anyone have actual experience with these devices?

Comment: I've updated the lambda to inquire as to the storage class- it does appear that such inquiries are an order of magnitude cheaper than requesting a copy, but it's unclear to me if you're charged for successful copy requests or all copy requests.